# View not resizing to simulator

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, interface-builder

I uploaded an starter project from Parse and when initially running the application in xcode the simulator view is padded above and below the UI:

[Screenshot of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3miZQ.png)

When I use preview on interface builder it shows the UI as filling out the screen - so no issues there.

I've tried:

1. Looking in attributes / size inspector - cannot see any clues
2. Looking at the simulator to see if I can alter preferences, no luck
3. Running simulator under difference devices, no luck

My question is: How do I resize the view to fit the simulator screen?

Thanks in advance. I'm new to Swift and Stack Overflow so apologies if this question lacks any technical merit.

Comment: What does it look like when you go home in the simulator? If you have a similar issue on your home screen, I would say it's an issue with the simulator and not the application.

Answer (score 0):

The project probably looks fine on an 4s simulator.

Try creating a LaunchScreen.storyboard and adding it as a launch screen in the project General settings. The project should then magically convert to a mode when it fills the screen rather than displaying the black padding on larger devices.

If the project uses Autolayout, the UI should fill the screen and look fine on screens of any size. Otherwise, it will fill the screen but might be distorted for larger screens (5s, 6, 6plus).